# R: plotting multiple lines on same graph using ggplot

Tags: r

I have a dataset called `data` that has the populations for certain areas for each year and it looks like this:

```
 Year   CityA CityB CityC
1 2005  3000  4000  2000
2 2006  4000  6000  3000
3 2007  5000  8000  7000
4 2008  6000  4000  5000
5 2009  7000  4000  9000
6 2010  8000  4000  6000
7 2011  9000  6000  7000
```

I want to plot  `CityA`, `CityB`, and `CityC` as lines on the same graph.

My code so far is:

```
data %>% gather(key = "City", value = "Population", -Year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = `Population`) +
  geom_line()
```

However, this doesn't plot correctly. Could somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The bracket should be closed `ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = `Population`))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the `col` in `aes` (Also, the `)` was missing in the `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Year, values_to = 'Population') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Population, col = name)) + 
     geom_line()
```

[image]

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Year = 2005:2011, CityA = c(3000L, 4000L, 5000L, 
6000L, 7000L, 8000L, 9000L), CityB = c(4000L, 6000L, 8000L, 4000L, 
4000L, 4000L, 6000L), CityC = c(2000L, 3000L, 7000L, 5000L, 9000L, 
6000L, 7000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```